# Changing colors of Process Explorer

Tags: process-explorer, sysinternals

I want to make my Process Explorer dark. I managed to change all colors except these very bright columns:

[image]

How can I change these bright colors to something dark?

Comment: I think you can't do that, maybe you should write to the authors and report it. It is a logical decision to add the option to color this 3 column too.

Comment: I'm curious how you were able to change those colors in the first place.  Can you give us a link or something that explains how you did that please?

Comment: [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) starting from version 17 has dark theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to uncheck "Show Column Heatmaps" in the view menu, but it's available only on procexp 15.31 or above.

Comment: Noted, I didn't think to look for that. Thanks for the points!

Answer (score 4):

Those columns appear to override the default Windows color scheme, and I'm not quite sure why. Short of using some kind of external tool to manipulate the running program (very hackish), your best bet is to ask for the feature on the [Sysinternals Forum](http://forum.sysinternals.com/).

Comment: It's dangerous out there. Take 50 points.